# ember-data: modeling a user-maintained list of products

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Trying to wrap my head around how to efficiently model and code a "saved items" list for logged-in users.

I want the user to be able to click "save item" from a product page, and it will add the item to a list kept in their user profile that has its own route that displays their items and allows them to manage the list.  On that route, anytime there are changes to the list (like, item is removed), it should refresh to reflect the changes.

I'd *think* the user model would look something like this:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
const { attr, belongsTo, hasMany } = DS;

export default DS.Model.extend({
    savedItems: hasMany('product'),
    ...
});
```

And then I can add items to it with this action:

```
actions: {
    addSavedItem(product) {
        this.get('store').findRecord('user', 'me').then(user => {
            user.get('savedItems').pushObject(product);
            user.save();
        });
    },
}
```

And load those saved items in my saved-items route like:

```
model() {
    return this.get("store").findRecord('user', 'me').then(user => {
        return user.get('savedItems');
    });
}
```

That works!  BUT...`product` passes in the entire product object.  Name, prices, description, etc.  Then `save` sends it all in the payload to the back end.  Then the back-end has to send it all back (I think) for this to stay working.

**Is there a way to have `savedItems` store *just* product IDs, and have ember-data load the rest of the product data as-needed?  Product ID is all I need to persist to the back end.**

I've tried removing the relationship and having `savedItems` be an array:

```
savedItems: attr('')
```

that stores just product IDs.  And I had partial success there.  But I can't figure out how to set up the `model` hook in the `saved-items` route so the it refreshes whenever there are changes to that list.

Any help appreciated!

**UPDATE:** Passing back just the product ids from the back end works - but only if the product is already in the store.

Comment: Have you tried using `user.get('savedItems').id()` or `.ids()`? Maybe you should use in `hasMany('product').id()` ? I remember seeing thins somewhere, but I can't remember :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself have setup such relationships that way:

```
// model user.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    savedItems: hasMany('savedItem'),
    ...
});

// model savedItem.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    //id- I have my ids in such a model as a string 'userID_productID'
    // just for convinience in the backend.
    user: belongsTo('user'),
    product: belongsTo('product'),
    someOtherPropertyUniqueToThatRelation: attr('string'), // like a status
    ...
});
```

then I simply add another record to the relationShip Model.

```
addSavedItem(product) {
    this.get('store').findRecord('user', 'me').then(user => {
        let safedItem = this.get('store').createRecord('safedItem', {
              user: user,
              product: product,
              otherProp: 'whatever'
        });
        safedItem.save();
    });
},
```

Now it's only sending the ids of user and product to the backend.

Maybe I'm doing it wrong, or this a strange approach, but that works fine for me in all situations.

Comment: Ahhh...that's good.  Also answers my question about how you would add fields that are specific to the savedItem without having to add them to product (where they don't belong).  Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: you are welcome! feel free to also accept this answer if it answers your question.

Comment: got any guidance about how to get the`saveditem` model's  `product` relationship to resolve (to a full product) when only the product ID is in the store?  I.e. in the 'saveditems' route where the user views their saved items, the items are there but all their data is empty because ember isn't fetching the product data.  Would this be where side-loading comes in?

Comment: please make this a seperate question. It should automaticly reload the child models. Depends on your model definition and how you request them.