# ember: computed property on ember-data store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am setting up a "saved item" feature for logged-in users.  I have the [modeling worked out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47602237/ember-data-modeling-a-user-maintained-list-of-products) already (it relates the saved item list to both the user and products).  But I am having trouble with how to have a computed property on my `saveditem` model.  The model:

```
// saveditem.js model
export default DS.Model.extend({

    user: belongsTo('user'),
    product: belongsTo('product'),
    dateAdded: attr('string')

});
```

I am currently using the product id as the `id` of that model.

I need a computed property on that model because anytime a product is shown on the site, the UI needs to reflect whether the item is already in the `saveditem` ember-data store or not.

Example of if the item is not on the list (but can be added):
[image]

Example of an item that is on the list (but can be removed):
[image]

I was thinking that on my `userprofile` service which manages the user's data across the app, I could have a computed property that outputs an array of ids from the `saveditem` model:

```
savedItemsList: computed('WHAT.IS.DEPENDENT.KEY?.[]', function() {
    return this.get('store').peekAll('saveditem').map(item => item.id);
}),
```

And then in the template I could use a composable helper to see if the item being displayed is in the list or not:

```
{{#if (contains product.id userprofile.savedItemsList)}}
    ...show already-saved button...
{{else}}
    ...show save button...
{{/if}}
```

**The question: what would the dependent key be for this computed property?  OR...is this method stinky and and there's a better way to do it?**

I have tried:

```
savedItemsList: computed('store.saveditem.[]', function() {
```

(after of course injecting the store).  Seems like the obvious one but it doesn't update when records are added or removed from the `saveditem` store.  Also tried `'store.saveditems.[]'`, permutations with and without array brackets, and NO dependent key - all no worky.

Makes me wonder whether this is not possible for a good reason ;)  I might be "fighting the framework" here.  Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can introduce computed property which will return all the items in the store and use that property for your `savedItemsList` computed property.

```
allSavedItemsList: computed(function() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('saveditem');
}),

savedItemsList: computed('allSavedItemsList.[]',function() {
    return this.get('store').peekAll('saveditem').map(item => item.id);
}),
```

Comment: Thanks!  That works.  One small change I needed to make was having the return value on `savedItemsList` be `this.get('allSavedItemsList').map(item => item.id);` because I think the `allSavedItemsList` CP needs to be referenced in order for it to execute.